# 'rotate' is not defined React.JS

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to make a rotating arrow based on wind direction (like on https://openweathermap.org/ when searching for a city). I tried to use the transform and rotate properties but I get the **'rotate' is not defined error**.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Conditions.module.css'
import moment from 'moment';
import Arrow from './arrow.png';

let compassSector = ["N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE", "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW", "N"];

const conditions = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={classes.Wrapper}>

            {props.error && <small className={classes.Small}>Please enter a valid city.</small>}

            {props.loading && <div className={classes.Loader} />}


            {props.responseObj.cod === 200 ?
                <div>
                    <p><strong>{props.responseObj.name}, {props.responseObj.sys.country}</strong></p>
                    <p className={classes.weather}>It is currently {Math.round(props.responseObj.main.temp)} degrees out with {props.responseObj.weather[0].description}.</p>
                    <p>Humidity: {props.responseObj.main.humidity}</p>
                    <p><img src={Arrow} alt="windarrow" style={{width: 14, transform: rotate(props.responseObj.wind.degdeg), height: 14}} /> Wind: {props.responseObj.wind.speed} m/s, {compassSector[(props.responseObj.wind.deg / 22.5).toFixed(0)]}</p>
                    <p>Sunrise is at: {moment(props.responseObj.sys.sunrise).format('hh:mm:ss a')} and sunset at: {moment(props.responseObj.sys.sunset).format('hh:mm:ss a')}</p>
                </div>
            : null
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default conditions;
```

I'm a beginner in React and I'm trying to kinda recreate the OpenWeatherMap forecast to learn React.JS and requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be a string, do it like this

```
transform: `rotate(${props.responseObj.wind.deg}deg)`
```

Notice I am using the the backtick character here `` (`) ``, it is the key to the left of the number `1` key to wrap text as a string and still allowing you to add JavaScript in it by wrapping any JavaScript like this `${code...}`

Comment: Now I got rid of the error but it's still not rotating. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, (assuming that `props.responseObj.wind.deg` is a number) the last `deg` needed to be outside of the curly brace, see my updated answer